# Excute powershell SCVMM cmdlets from Asp.Net Web API

Tags: c#, powershell, api, rest

I'm developing a Web Api in Asp.Net. I need that the web API comunicates with SCVMM, using .Net Framework.
We all know that SCVMM does not provide an API o interface similar to execute functions from c# code, but we have the option to run commands from PowerShell.

The situation is as follows:

1. From PowrShell prompt I can comunicate without any problem with SCVMM
2. From c# code using Cake.Pworsehl Nuget Package I can execute cmdlets with SCVMM commands
   and comunicate with SCVNMM without problems.
3. Using the functions that I've wrote before, I've created a Dll with all the
   functionality that I need, I have also added a TestProject for that dll and all works
   fine.
4. The problem is that when I call the same functions from the WebApi project using
   debugmode in VS 2022 I have the following error:

`System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: 'You do not have access to the  management server VMM NO_PARAM. (Error Id: 1604)`

The weird thing is that, as I said before, I can run all funcitons from PowerShell prompt, and execute all the code from TestProjects and even a console application, but if I call the same functions form web api, I get that error.

I'm thinking that the problemas has to be realted with de Identity or something similar, but I can not found any way to specify credentials for run powershell cmdlets form c# code.

This is the function that gives me the error:

```
public List<Vm> GetVMsBase()
{

    InitialSessionState initialSessionState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
    initialSessionState.ExecutionPolicy = ExecutionPolicy.Unrestricted;
    initialSessionState.ImportPSModule(new string[] { "virtualmachinemanager" });            

    using (var myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialSessionState))
    {
          myRunSpace.Open();
          using (var pipeLine = myRunSpace.CreatePipeline())
          {
                Command cmd = new Command("Get-SCVirtualMachine");
                cmd.Parameters.Add("VMMServer", "vmmserver.domain.com");
                pipeLine.Commands.Add(cmd);

                return pipeLine.Invoke().Select(vm =>
                new Vm
                {
                    Name = vm.Properties["name"].Value.ToString(),
                    Owner = ((string[])vm.Properties["CustomProperties"].Value)[1],
                    ExpirationDate = DateTime.TryParse(
                                ((string[])vm.Properties["CustomProperties"].Value)[0], new CultureInfo("es-ES"), DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dt) ?
                                dt : new DateTime(1800, 1, 1),
                    CreationDate = DateTime.TryParse(
                                vm.Properties["CreationTime"].Value.ToString(), new CultureInfo("es-ES"), DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dt2) ?
                                dt2 : new DateTime(1800, 1, 1),
                    Hlnumber = ((string[])vm.Properties["CustomProperties"].Value)[2],
                    State = Enum.TryParse(vm.Properties["VirtualMachineState"].Value.ToString(), out VirtualMachineState vmState) ? vmState : VirtualMachineState.Unknow
                }).ToList();

                if (pipeLine.Error != null && pipeLine.Error.Count > 0)
                {
                    //check error
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there any way to call or run this code from web api?

thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finaly I'v solved this problem, there was nothing wrong with the code to run powershell cmdlets, the problem was with the configuration of IIS expres (in visual studio) and when deploy the api in IIS 10.

In both cases I have to setup de configuration in a way that Anonymous logon was disabled and the only Authettication method used was "Windows", and that's it.

In IIS express you have to edit the .config file located in the .vs directory of the solution, and in IIS 10 you have to edit your site setting in the Authetication Options.